# Binding to Object Property in ViewModel issue

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datacontext, access-modifiers

Not sure why this isn't working... Below I is my ViewModel which is set to my View DataContext.

```
public class UploadViewModel : CrudVMBase
    {
        #region Commands
        public CommandVM UploadButtonCommand { get; set; } =
            new CommandVM
            {
                CommandDisplay = "Perform Upload",
                IconGeometry = App.Current.Resources["pencil30"] as Geometry,
                Message = new CommandMessage { Command = CommandType.UploadFromCamera }
            };
        #endregion End Commands

        #region Public Properties
        UploadInitiation UploadObject { get; set; } = new UploadInitiation();
        #endregion End Public Properties

        public UploadViewModel()
        {

        }
```

Below is the UploadInitiation class

```
public class UploadInitiation : Common.NotifyUIBase
    {
        #region Public Properties
            public ObservableCollection<UploadStep> Steps { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<UploadStep>();
            public int UploadProgress { get; set; } = 45;
            public string UploadTask { get; set; } = "Idle...";
            public bool UploadEnabled { get; set; } = false;
            public bool UploadBegin { get; set; } = false;
        #endregion END Public Properties

        public UploadInitiation()
        {
            // Populate steps required, ensure upload returns UI updates
            Steps.Add(new UploadStep { Message = "Seperate upload to new thread...", Complete = false, Error = null });
            Steps.Add(new UploadStep { Message = "Generate new file names...", Complete = false, Error = null });
            Steps.Add(new UploadStep { Message = "Render Thumbnails, add to database...", Complete = false, Error = null });
            Steps.Add(new UploadStep { Message = "Move images ready for print...", Complete = false, Error = null });
        }
    }
```

This is my Binding, as you can see im trying to Bind to the `UploadProgress` Property.

```
<ProgressBar Style="{StaticResource CircularProgress}" Width="180" Value="{Binding UploadObject.UploadProgress}" />
```

Here is the error

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'UploadObject' property not found on 'object' ''UploadViewModel'
>   (HashCode=33902366)'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=UploadObject.UploadProgress;
>   DataItem='UploadViewModel' (HashCode=33902366); target element is
>   'ProgressBar' (Name=''); target property is 'Value' (type 'Double')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make declare the scope of the property to **public**, or it will be private by default. Hence it was not visible when binding.

```
public UploadInitiation UploadObject { get; set; } = new UploadInitiation();
```

Comment: What an idiot I am! I was convinced I had done that... I even read it multiple times! Thanks!